# how to process a set of urls instead of one url per time?

Tags: java

lets say i have a list of urls such as

http://stackexchange.com
  https://stackoverflow.com/users/login
  http://careers.stackoverflow.com
  http://chat.stackoverflow.com
  http://meta.stackoverflow.com
  https://stackoverflow.com/about

this list is in a text file.

now i would like to process all the urls in one go. The below coding is the processor.

```
String sourceUrlString="http://stackexchange.com";
    if (args.length==0)
      System.err.println("Using default argument of \""+sourceUrlString+'"');
    else
        sourceUrlString=args[0];
    if (sourceUrlString.indexOf(':')==-1) sourceUrlString="file:"+sourceUrlString;
    Source source=new Source(new URL(sourceUrlString));
    String renderedText=source.getRenderer().toString();
    System.out.println("\nSimple rendering of the HTML document:\n");
    System.out.println(renderedText);
```

as you see, the coding above only can process one url at one time where i must manually key in the url at the sourceurlstring. How do i process all of the urls in the text file in one go ?

Comment: Loon - you should probably spend some time learning basic Java programming ... before you embark on your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Learn what methods are by reading [this part of the Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).
- Implement a method taking one URL as argument and processing it.
- Learn how to read a text file by reading [this part of the Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html).
- Implement a method to read the text file line by line, and call your first method for each line read in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take advantage of Multithreading.

This should get you started on the right path:  [The Basics of Multiple Threads in Java](http://www.devshed.com/index2.php?option=content&task=view&id=1616&pop=1&hide_ads=1&page=0&hide_js=1)

Comment: I think he needs to start by iterating before jumping into multithreading.

Comment: I don't think he means all at the same time, but rather how can he read each url from the text file.

Comment: apologies if I misunderstood. "all the urls in one go" sounded like he needed multithreading.

Comment: @Gugussee: given that the OP says that he must manually key in the url at the sourceurlstring (rather than making it an argument of the program), I'd rather think that he's looking for how to read a text file and call a method for each line.